# How to create Protractor Job on jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, protractor

Try to run e2e specs with jenkins, install jenkins on ubuntu 16.04 sucessfully, then in jenkins dashboard i clicked on New Item and select Freestyle Project then after click on next General settings page will open. In general page i'll select Github project and mention project url after that i'll goto next section "Source Code Management" in which i am selecting Git and paste Git repository URL but it will give me a error

> Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h
>   https://github.com/repo_name" returned status code 128: stdout: 
>   stderr: remote: Invalid username or password.

[image]

Comment: enter proper github url there and give credential info if it is a private project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) No need to check the `GitHub project` in `General` Tab

2) In `Source Code Managerment`, need a valid git repo url which ends with `.git`.

For github repo, you can get the repo url as following:
   [image]

Example:  https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js.git

3) In `Credentials`, if repo not require account to access, you can leave `Credentials` with `-none-` selected.

4) In `Branch Specifier`, if your code in branch: master, you can set `*/master`
   If in branch: develop, you can set `*/develop`, or other branch `*/<branch name>`